Voltage on circuit in house rises when turning on oven. What can I do to diagnose and fix this issue?
I have appliances (fans, tv, and tube lights) flickering and/or shutting off. When I turn two of my oven burners on the flickering stops, the fan speeds back up and the tv turns on permanently with no more flickering.
I measure the voltage in the outlet with the tv and fan while the electric burner (runs on 240V) is turned on and see it jump from ~95-100 up to ~110.
When I measure at the breaker where 240V comes into the house here is what I find between all 3 wires that come into the house. I measure 120V between ground and live  (it’s hard to tell what’s what because the electrical work was done DIY) and then I measure 95V between the other two. Then I measure about 30V between what I think is neutral and ground.
First, What tests can I carry out when I am out there next time so that I can determine what the problem is?
Second, how can I tell if there is a short somewhere between the property’s main breaker and the house? How to find the short?
Third, how can I tell if it is a disconnected wire? (I have read online about a lost neutral).
Fourth, how can I tell if it is the transformer on the pole malfunctioning?

Lost neutral. CALL YOUR UTILITY.

lost neutral
